# Setup SSL Certificate for multiple ports using 1 domain name

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, centos8

I need to setup ssl for 2 websites: admin and client, with the same domain *abc.example.com* but different port.

1. The admin page, you need to setup:

- http: 8080
- https: 8443
- root /var/www/admin/public

```
server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name abc.example.com;
        root /var/www/admin/public;
        index index.php;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        location ~ \.php$ {
           try_files $uri =404;
           fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           include fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
         }

        location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }
    }

   server {
         listen 8443 ssl;
         server_name abc.example.com;
         root /var/www/admin/public;
         index index.php;
         error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
         access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

         ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/_example.com.crt;
         ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/certs/_example.com.key;
         location ~ \.php$ {
           try_files $uri =404;
           fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           include fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
         }
    
        location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }
    }
```

2. The client page, you need to setup:

- http: 80
- https: 443
- root /var/www/client/public

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name abc.example.com;
        root /var/www/client/public;
        index index.php;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        location ~ \.php$ {
           try_files $uri =404;
           fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           include fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
         }

        location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }
    }

     server {
         listen 443 ssl;
         server_name abc.example.com;
         index index.php;
         error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
         access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
         ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/_example.com.crt;
         ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/certs/_example.com.key;
         root /var/www/client/public;
         location ~ \.php$ {
           try_files $uri =404;
           fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           include fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
         }
        
        location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        } 
    }
```

I have the above config, the port 80,443,8080 is connected successfully but port 8443 is not working. Although on the server I have already opened port 8443.
[image]

Specifically, when I access the link *https://abc.example.com:8443/*, the browser says *this site can't be reached*
[image]

If anybody face the problem and know how to fix it.Hope you'll help me to solve it. Thank you so much!

Comment: What does not working mean? You are missing a `root` and `index` statement in one of your `server` blocks.

Comment: Can you specify what is the problem? The config looks good at the first glance.

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh Specifically, when I access the link https://abc.example.com:8443/, the browser says "this site can't be reached"

Comment: @RichardSmith I added root and index but still the error "this site can't be reached"

Comment: If the same server is reachable with the same name over different ports, either the server is not listening on port 8443, or there is a firewall in between which is blocking port 8443.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thank you very much, I have added port 8443 to my firewall and have accessed the website from that port.